# Split vector such that means of two groups are nearly equal

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` with 2 variables A and B. I would like to split A in groups 1 and 2 so that `mean(df$B[df$group==1])` as close as possible to `mean(df$B[df$group==2])`

Or just to express it otherwise,  what I would like is to find a cut point (`cutp`) in `df$A` that would minimize the `abs(mean(df$B[df$A<cutp])-mean(df$B[df$A>=cutp]))`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do groups 1 and 2 have to be equal?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Groups 1 and 2 should have approximately the same number of cases (or at least no big differences).

Comment: Does variable A play any role in the question?

Comment: I don't get your comment Vincent.

Comment: Your data.frame contains two columns, A and B, and you write that you want to "split A" (not "split df") into two groups, which suggests that column A should be used in the splitting -- yet, it does not explicitly appear in your condition.

Comment: Yes it does. It appears as group==1 and group==2. I want to split A in 2 groups, so that the mean(b) OF EACH GROUP is as close as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find a threshold on variable A, to split the data into two groups, so that the means of B in those two groups be similar, you can compute these means for all possible cut-points, and check when the distance between those means is minimal.

```
# Sample data
n <- 10
d <- data.frame(
  A = rnorm(n),
  B = rnorm(n)
)

# The quantity to minimize
# (You can use a loop instead of apply.)
d$differences <- apply(
  d, 1, 
  # Compute the difference of the means for each value of A
  function (u) { 
    i <- d$A <= u[1]; 
    abs( mean( d$B[which(i)]) - mean(d$B[which(!i)] ) )
  } 
)
# The mean of an empty vector is NaN: discard those values
d$differences[ ! is.finite( d$differences ) ] <- Inf
# Take the minimum
threshold <- d$A[ which.min( d$differences ) ]
# Build the groups
d$group <- ifelse( d$A <= threshold, "group 1", "group 2" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure how column A factors into it. It seems you want to create a new column that has two levels which create ~= mean values for column B. Column A is obviously associated with the new column created, but does not directly factor into the calculation needed. Am I missing something?

Regardless, here's a start (note this can be made much more robust, but proof of concept should work). Define a tolerance that you find acceptable and then set up a while loop to create new groups until the condition is met, i.e.

```
FUN <- function(tol){
  df$groups <- sample(1:2, nrow(df), TRUE)

  while(abs(mean(df$B[df$groups == 1]) - mean(df$B[df$groups == 2])) > tol) {
    df$groups <- sample(1:2, nrow(df), TRUE)
  }
  return(df)
}

set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame(A=runif(20),B=runif(20))

#Test it. Means should be less than .02 different and have roughly equivalent sample sizes.
set.seed(101)
out <- FUN(.02)
library(plyr)
> ddply(out, "groups", summarize, n = length(B), mean = mean(B))
  groups  n      mean
1      1 11 0.5229024
2      2  9 0.5037279
```

I should note that you could create a runaway function if you set `tol` super low so don't blame me if your computer crashes.