# Split Data into groups of equal means

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to split a data frame into groups of equal size (essentially same number of rows in each group), whose groups have a nearly equal mean.

> `User  Data
>
>   1     5.0
>
>   2     4.5
>
>   3     3.5
>
>   4     6.0
>
>   5     7.0
>
>   6     6.5
>
>   7     5.5
>
>   8     6.2
>
>   9     5.7
>
>   10    5.9`

This is very similar to [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865838/split-vector-such-that-means-of-two-groups-are-nearly-equal)  However this only splits the data into 2 groups.

My actual dataset contains anywhere from 75-150 rows, and I need to split it into anywhere from 5-10 groups of equal mean and fairly equal size.

I've researched on Google & Stack Exchange for the last few days, and I'm just not having much luck.  Any guidance would be great.

Thanks in advance!

More details:

Maybe I need to provide some more details, below I've included a real dataset.  We are a transportation company, this data set has Driver ID, Miles, Gallons provided.  What I have been doing is reading the data into R, and adding and MPG column like so:

```
data <- read.csv('filename')  
data$MPG <- data$Miles / data$Gallons
```

Then I tried the two provided answers below.  Arun's idea gives me almost equal group sizes (9 members per group, 10 groups), however the variation of the means is large, from 6.615 - 7.093 which is too large of a variation for me to start off with.  Thomas' idea gets a little bit tighter variation, but the group sizes are all different from 6 - 13 members.

What we are looking to do is improve fleet MPG, and we're going to accomplish this with a team based competition, so I need to randomly put the teams together with them all starting from relatively the same group MPG.

Maybe that helps and can lead us in the correct direction?  I tried doing this just in my programming language, but it locks the computer up every time, so I figured that R would probably be able to process the data better.

Thanks again!

Comment: I think this is related to [**partition problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) in case you're interested.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, you provided me with a solution that will work for the datasets I generate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If similar means is really all that matters, I've put together a simulation below that basically looks at a bunch of different combinations of the data (`n`) for a particular group size (`k`) and then minimizes the variance of the group means. With that minimization you can then extract that grouping from the simulation results.

```
df <- data.frame(User=1:1000,Data=rnorm(1000,0,1))     # example data
myfun = function(){
    k <- 5                                             # number of groups
    tmp <- seq(length(mpg))%%ngroups                   # really efficient code from @qwwqwwq's answer
    thisgroup <- sample(tmp, dim(df)[1], FALSE)        # pull a sample
    # thisgroup <- sample(1:k,dim(df)[1],TRUE)         # original version
    thisavg <- as.vector(by(df$Data, thisgroup, mean)) # group means
    thisvar <- var(thisavg)                            # variance of means
    return(list(group=thisgroup, avgs=thisavg, var=thisvar))
}
n <- 1000 # number of simulations
sorts <- replicate(n, myfun(), simplify=FALSE)
wh <- which.min(sapply(sorts, function(x) x$var))      # minimization
# sorts[[wh]]                   # this is the sample you want
split(df, sorts[[wh]]$group)    # list of separate dataframes for each group
```

You could also have `k` of different sizes, if you don't care about how many cases are in each group by just moving the `k <- 5` line into the function and having it be a random draw from the range of number of groups you're willing to have.

There are probably other ways to do this, though.

Comment: doesn't seem right: I think the OP wants to split the data in disjoint  subsets, while your code compares groups that can have elements in common, as far as I can see

Comment: @BenBolker That seems like a comment for the OP, not this answer.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the sample() bit, sorry!

Comment: @baptiste No worries. I was just going to comment that I bet it's the `sample` part that was confusing.

Comment: I think i spoke too soon.  Your answer gives me less variation in the group means, however, the groups are all random sizes from 6 data points to 13 data points in each group.  I really need to get it very similar in the number of data points per group.  I'm going to edit the original question and provide more details.

Comment: @dcmoody Take a look at the edit. Play with the value of `k`, but this version will force groups to have the exact same size +/-1.

Answer (score 3):

Going by Thomas' idea, here's a brute-force/greedy approach, which'll give more or less the same values (you can opt for more repetitions until you agree with the closeness of the solution).

```
# Assuming the data you provided is in `df`
grp <- 5
myfun <- function() {
    samp <- sample(nrow(df))
    s.mean <- tapply(df$Data, samp %% grp, mean)
    s.var <- var(s.mean)
    list(samp, s.mean, s.var)
}
out <- replicate(1000, myfun(), simplify=FALSE)
min.pos <- which.min(sapply(out, `[[`, 3))
min.idx <- out[[min.pos]][[1]]
split(df$Data[min.idx], min.idx %% grp)

$`0`
[1] 7.0 5.9

$`1`
[1] 5.0 6.5

$`2`
[1] 5.5 4.5

$`3`
[1] 6.2 3.5

$`4`
[1] 5.7 6.0
```

---

This is how `out[min.pos]` looks like:

```
out[min.pos]

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1]  7  9  8  5  3  4  1  2 10  6

[[1]][[2]]
   0    1    2    3    4 
5.85 5.70 5.60 5.25 5.50 

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 0.05075
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I can think of: Sort the data, modulo all the indicies by the number of groups, and you're done. Should work well if the data are normally distributed I think. Has the advantage of the groups being as equally sized as possible.

```
mpg <- rnorm(150)
mpg <- sort(mpg)
ngroups = 13
df = data.frame( mpg=mpg, group=seq(length(mpg))%%ngroups)
tapply(df$mpg, df$group, mean)

           0            1            2            3            4            5            6            7            8 
 0.080400272 -0.110797283 -0.046698548 -0.014177675  0.024410834  0.048370962  0.066265303  0.087119914 -0.062259638 
           9           10           11           12 
-0.042172496 -0.003451581  0.033853024  0.056947458
```